# Subclipse tree conflicts

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control, merge, subclipse

I'm trying to merge a trunk to a branch, but ending up with a lot of tree conflicts, leaving no files merged. To resolve the conflicts, I'm just opening the file and copying contents by hand which just defeats the purpose of a merge operation. 
What is the right way to merge a trunk to a branch (in subclipse) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How was that branch created? Was it created by using `svn cp`, or were those files manually copied into that branch?

Let's look at the following:

```
$ svn mkdir trunk
$ vi trunk/foo trunk/bar
$ svn add trunk/foo trunk/bar
$ svn commit -m"Added foo and bar to trunk"
```

You now have two files on trunk.

```
$ svn mkdir --parents branches/1.0
$ cp trunk/* branches/1.0/
$ svn add branches/1.0/*
$ svn commit -m"Duplicated files onto branch"
```

What I have done is create two entirely different `foo` and `bar` on the 1.0 branch. These two files, according to Subversion have absolutely nothing to do with each other. If you make a change on the 1.0 branch, and attempt to merge these changes back to trunk, you will get a lot of conflicts with messages like "local add, incoming add".

What the above user should have done is this:

```
$ svn cp --parents trunk branches/1.0
$ svn commit -m"Branched trunk and not merely duplicate files"
```

Now, there's a relationship that Subversion understands between the files on trunk and on the 1.0 branch. Merging will go smoothly.

Here's another way to break a merge:

```
$ svn delete trunk/foo
$ svn commit -"deleted foo"
$ svn cat -rPREV trunk/foo@PREV > foo
$ svn add foo
$ svn commit -m"Added foo back in. Shouldn't have deleted it.
```

According to Subversion, there are now two completely different files named `foo` in the trunk. There's the file you deleted, and there's the file you added. These two files have nothing to do with each other. Imagine if I branched (the correct way using `svn cp`) to the 1.0 branch, then did my delete and copy of `foo`. The merge of the 1.0 branch back to trunk will have a conflict because the `foo` on the branch has no relationship with the `foo` on trunk.

To restore a file, you need to copy the revision that was deleted (or use `svn merge -c`).

```
$ svn cp -rPREV http://svn.repo/svn/trunk/foo@PREV .
$ svn commit -m"Actually old foo now has been restored! Merges will work"
```

If you branched incorrectly, or deleted and re-added files back to trunk, you will get conflicts. You can try using the `--ignore-ancestory` parameter, and you can use `--dry-run` to test your merge before running the actual merge.

If you manually merge, you can use `svn merge --record-only` to just record the fact you did a merge without actually doing one. This might help the next time you do a merge since you're at least recoding what you've manually done.

Comment: If the branch was not created using svn cp, will it's history contain the trunk's history too till that point? as I can see the trunk's log in the branch's history. Anyways, now I know the correct way of branching to avoid merge errors, thanks for the detailed answer.